# HttpClient request on networked docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-network

I am new to docker containers and Im running into the following issue. I am developing a web page that makes requests to an exposed api. Both of them are published on different containers that are linked through a network. 
This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  api:
    image: my/api
    networks:
      - api
    ports:
      - "8080:5000"    
    container_name: api  

  web:
    build:
      context: ./DockerWeb      
    networks:
      - api      
    ports:
      - "80:5000"    
    container_name: web

networks:    
  api:
    driver: bridge
```

I have noticed that if I attach to the container running my webpage I can ping the api container without any issue using `ping api`

The issue comes when trying to make any web service call to the api container. I am trying to initialize an HttpClient object, however the BaseAddress property of such an object must be set to a valid Uri.

```
_client = new HttpClient();
_client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.ApiUrl); //config.ApiUrl = "api"
```

This throws the following error

> UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Is there a way to either a) Expose the container name in a different way, or b) make a call to a web service without the need of using a URI?
How can I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I have updated the ApiUrl to contain the value `http:api:8080`, however now I am getting an exception when performing the call

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.) ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't connect to server

I have also tried the calling the api endpoint directly from my web container using wget

```
wget http://api:8080/
```

However I still receive back an error:

> Connecting to api (api)|172.24.0.4|:8080... failed: Connection refused

Could this be an API configuration error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`api` is just the hostname. The URI would be `http://api:8080` (or `https://api:someotherport` if you set up SSL/TLS.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have updated to call http:api:8080, however I am getting an exception "System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't connect to server" I have also tried the following from my web container `wget http://api:8080/` and I receive back the following error: Connecting to api (api)|172.24.0.4|:8080... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: I noticed that even though I am exposing the port 8080 for the api, this is NOT the used port between containers. Between containers in the same network, the port exposed by the EXPOSE instruction is used. In this case, it would be 5000. Trying to http://api:5000/ worked

Comment: @LuisBecerril Sorry. I must have go confused with the order of the port binding in docker compose yml files.

Answer (score 1):

The internal port is used for connections inside the docker network. So in this case it is the request needs to go to http://api:5000

Answer (score 0):

Here there is 2 kinds of communication:

**Container web > Container api**

In this case, indeed, you can just use the hostname "api" to connect to your api.
This is what you would have to do if your html is generated server side.

**Web Client > Container api**

Here however I suppose that you are using some kind of JavaScript web application (Angular or other). In that case the html (and the call) is not made from the web container but directly from your web browser.

So in that case you have to use http://localhost:8080 (I suppose that Docker is running on your local machine).

I hope it helps

Comment: I cannot use localhost:8080 since this would break the container naming linking. I need to use http://api:8080 so that the ip address of the api container gets resolved on runtime. Still I cannot connect

Comment: I didn't mean to use localhost in the docker-compose file. Here the problem is that your client connect from outside Docker, so the container links are not used here. Can you maybe confirm at least if using localhost works (in your web app) and confirm or not if you are using this call in a JavaScript web app using something like Angular